# How to inject content script view on the PDF viewer?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that will use `content_script` to inject an iframe that will be a container of the popup.html. Everything is working fine, however, when testing it on a PDF viewer it does not correctly show on the PDF viewer as shown below.

[image]

On my codes, this is what I'm doing.

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
    const contentScript = new ContentScript();

    switch (request.action) {
        case "browser_action_click":
            contentScript.injectIframe();
            break;
        // remove codes from brevity
    }
    return true;
})

    export class ContentScript {
        injectIframe() {
            const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

            iframe.setAttribute("id", "popup-iframe");
            iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");

            // inject
            if (document.body) {
                document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.lastChild);
            }

            iframe.onload = () => {
                iframe.style.height = "428px";
            }
        }
    }
```

**content_script.css**

```
#popup-iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 14px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
```

I also check on other extension and they were able to show their extension view correctly like the Evernote as shown below.

[image]

How do they correctly inject the iframe?

Comment: @wOxxOm it does run. it does inject the view but the behavior is different in PDF viewer.

Comment: Ah, the first screenshot now makes sense. You need `iframe.style.position = 'fixed'` and set `.top`, `.right` etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm I already did that on the css file counter part of content_script. let me just update my question to include the css.

Comment: Well, simply try to set the style on the element itself. You can do it interactively in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok. haha I did even try doing the inline style. It does work now :)

Comment: BTW, simply use `appendChild` instead of `insertBefore`. Currently you're inserting your iframe before the PDF viewer element, which is wrong I think.

Comment: @wOxxOm If you don't mind what is the difference? I know both will insert the iframe.

Comment: Well, it's just overcomplicated for no gain.

Comment: @rpmansion, Your current use of [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is not exactly the same as `appendChild()`. Your use inserts your `iframe` prior to the `body.lastChild`. Using `appendChild()` will insert the `iframe` after the current `body.lastChild`, as the new `body.lastChild`. Which to use will depend on where you want your `iframe` in the DOM. I would've assumed you would want it either first (i.e. `document.body.insertBefore(iframe,document.body.firstChild)`, or last). You should use what works for what you are desiring to do.