# Execute script on Chrome PDF Viewer

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Hi i am working on a chrome extension that inject a script into the web page and it's working
fine on any other website but not on pdf files.

after some research i understand that the pdf viewer is an application/plugin that is executed inside the webpage so any script goes the the web page but not the pdf.

is there any way to execute java script on the page like just a `console.log()` nothing hard.

and thank you

edit: MVC

Manifest.js:

```
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},


"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
```

Example Script: store the current position of the scroll wheel

```
let purl = window.location.toString();


if(purl.match(/pdf$/g)){
  //alert("PDF's are not supported... For now ");
  
Posp=document.querySelector("#viewer").shadowRoot.querySelector("#scroller").scrollTop;
//this always return 0 because it's not executing inside the pdf viewer but the source tab
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the source, which shows the PDF file? If not, there's nothing you can do because the browser decides how to process the `application/pdf` MIME type. Otherwise, you could try to encapsulate the PDF into an `iframe`. Then you could inject your custom JavaScript into the DOM.

Comment: Content scripts can run on PDF files so you need to show an [MCVE](/help/mcve) with your code and manifest.json.

Comment: @AlexGru can you please explain how that works i try not to mess with the user's webpage a lot so will this be noticeable

Comment: @wOxxOm is it good now?

Comment: @ayoubnay go check out similar questions like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971615/chrome-extension-inject-content-script-when-viewing-a-pdf

Comment: Indeed, you won't be able to access the internals. There's only a couple of useful commands e.g. [getSelectedText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61076939).

Comment: @wOxxOm i would like to control the "document" element if possible and not the text